# how this keyword works inside constructor for static variable

Tags: java

```
public class Tester {
    static int x = 4;
    public Tester() {
        System.out.print(this.x); //no error
        Tester();
    }
    public static void Tester() { // line 8
        System.out.print(this.x); // compilation error
    }
    public static void main(String... args) { // line 12
        new Tester();
}
```

In this example how can we access a static variable using this keyword inside constructor. But not in methods. this is keyword for current object reference, is n't it?

Comment: You're in a static method, there is no current object.

Answer (score 0):

Tricky, you are actually not in a constructor:

```
public static void Tester() { // line 8
    System.out.print(this.x); // compilation error
}
```

As you can see this is actually a *static method* named `Tester` (pretty confusing code, a good reason why method names should start with lowercase letters and classnames and constructor names start with an uppercase letter).

If you remove `static void` from the declaration you will be able to access the non-static members correctly:

```
public Tester() { // Now this is a constructor
    System.out.print(this.x); // no compilation error
}
```

Furthermore, the variable now does not have to be static (it shouldn't). You can just declare it as an instance variable like this:

```
private int x;
```

If you simply wish to access the static version of x, just write

```
Tester.x = 5;

// or from a static method in class Tester
x = 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

A `static` method is a method that belongs to the class, not to any specific instance. `this`, on the other hand, is a keyword referring to the current instance, so it cannot be used in a `static` method. However, since `x` is a static variable, you can use it from a `static` method:

```
public static void Tester() {
    System.out.print(x); // no "this" here
}
```